# SQL query to get result based on input from duplicate record

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have requirement like based on Category column get result.
for example i want query based on Category 'A'.Now in result rows will be there which all belongs to Category 'A' as well as Category 'Common' but if Category 'A' and Category 'Common' Name Same then get 'A' Category row not 'Common' one row.

I have tried the following query but expected result not coming.

```
    select 
* from (select t1.Id, t1.Name,t1.Category from 
(Select mt.Id,mt.Name,mt.Category from MyTable mt where Category='Common' ) as t1
full outer join
(Select Id,Name,Category from MyTable where Category='A') as t2
on t1.Name = t2.Name) as t3
```

Current Result:
[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6b0998a4ac64eb102a5a89807b27b662)

Expected/Required Result

```html
<table>
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Id</th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Category</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td class="">123</td>
             <td class="">Test</td>
             <td class="">A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td class="">456</td>
             <td class="">Test1</td>
             <td class="">A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td class="">345</td>
             <td class="">Test2</td>
             <td class="">A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td class="">234</td>
             <td class="">Test5</td>
             <td class="">A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td class="">675</td>
             <td class="">Test6</td>
             <td class="">A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td class="">676</td>
             <td class="">Test7</td>
             <td class="">Common</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

How to approach this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the required output here.

Comment: @Gudwlk if you see current/actual result as dbfiddle and required/expected result as snippet added.

Comment: why first record Name = Test ?

Comment: i have updated question

Comment: @Gudwlk Expected output using query is :    In result all rows will be there which all belongs to Category 'A' as well as Category 'Common' but if Category 'A' and Category 'Common'  exists with same Name then get 'A' Category row not 'Common' one row.

Comment: I will try to give u an answer. thanks for explanations

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution matching your new sample:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    MyTable     T
WHERE   T.Category  =   'A'

UNION   ALL

SELECT  *
FROM    MyTable     T
WHERE   T.Category  =   'Common'
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    MyTable         SQ
            WHERE   SQ.Name         =   T.Name
            AND     SQ.Category     =   'A'
        )
```

Comment: i think t's look correct for me..i need to test some scenario once

Comment: ok, please let me know if it works or if it needs another adjustment

Answer (score 1):

I divide the problem in to three, Refer to the comments added in the code. You can get the idea from comments to get the rows based on the conditions that you need to fulfil. Please go through the result carefully. I still doubt the first record. Let me know if you need an alteration.

According to your comment:
@Gudwlk Expected output using query is : In result all rows will be there which all belongs to Category 'A' as well as Category 'Common' but if Category 'A' and Category 'Common' exists with same Name then get 'A' Category row not 'Common' one row. –

```
 SELECT DISTINCT TB.* 
 FROM 
 
 (          

SELECT *
FROM myTable  
WHERE  Category ='A'  --Get the results for A

 UNION ALL

 --Get the results for Common where Category 'A' and Common matches by Name, then Replace Category 'Common' by 'A'
SELECT  
  A.Id
 ,A.[Name]
 ,A.Category

FROM 
(
        SELECT *
        FROM myTable  
        WHERE  Category ='A' ) AS A 
            INNER JOIN 
    (   SELECT * 
        FROM myTable  
        WHERE Category ='Common') AS B 
            ON A.[Name] = B.[Name]

 UNION ALL

--Get the rows of Category ='Common' Which [Name] is not equal to Category'A' [Name]
 SELECT 
    Id
    ,[Name]
    ,Category

FROM myTable  WHERE Category ='Common'
AND [Name] NOT IN  (SELECT [Name]
        FROM myTable  
        WHERE  Category ='A' )

        ) AS TB 
    ORDER BY TB.[Name]
```

[image: Result]

Comment: @r08 Check the answer and get back to me if you have any concerns. Thanks

Comment: This answer is based on your insert statements provided in fiddle. I think you need to alter your question, expected output section according to your insert statements.

Comment: result is wrong...it return 'A' related and Single 'Common'... but expected result always will be  includes everything given category(here it is 'A') as well as 'common' which all not same 'Name' of 'A'....whatever whatever insert stmt there no matter

Comment: And also Id always will be unique in same table

Comment: @r08 can you provide the insert statements with few correct data. Since your insert statements has same id twice, the result is based on the insert statement? if posible, give me the correct insert statements and the output related to that insert statements. So I can have the fix. Thanks :)

Comment: yes updated Id as well as required result

Comment: @r08 check the new answer please

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the below code. I added this as a new post.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT TB.* 
 FROM 
 
 (          

   SELECT *
  FROM myTable  
  WHERE  Category ='A'  --Get the results for A

   UNION ALL

  --Get the results for Common where Category 'A' and Common matches by Name, then Replace Category 'Common' by 'A'
   SELECT  
    A.Id
   ,A.[Name]
   ,A.Category
   FROM 
   (
        SELECT *
        FROM myTable  
        WHERE  Category ='A' ) AS A 
            INNER JOIN 
    (   SELECT * 
        FROM myTable  
        WHERE Category ='Common') AS B 
            ON A.[Name] = B.[Name]

    UNION ALL

   --Get the rows of Category ='Common' Which [Name] is not equal to Category'A' [Name]
   SELECT 
    Id
    ,[Name]
    ,Category

FROM myTable  WHERE Category ='Common'
AND [Name] NOT IN  (SELECT [Name]
        FROM myTable  
        WHERE  Category ='A' )

        ) AS TB 
 ORDER BY TB.[Name]
```

Comment: @r08 it is just an error occured when inserting the result image. I just removed the image.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . you seem to want one row per name where `name` has a row with `'common'`.  But, if there are two rows, you want the not-common row.

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by (case when category <> 'common' then 1 else 2 end)) as seqnum,
             sum(case when category = 'common' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name) as num_common
      from mytable t
     ) t
where num_common > 0 and seqnum = 1;
```

If you have only these three columns, you can also aggregation with fancy conditional logic:

```
select coalesce(max(case when category <> 'common' then id end),
                max(id)
               ) as id,
       name,
       coalesce(max(case when category <> 'common' then category end)
                max(category)
               )
from t
group by name
having sum(case when category = 'common' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Comment: I have lot of records in table but condition is only for result ...if record match Name between Category then get particular record otherwise common row of same Name.
 so in my case Name 'Test1' exists in Category A as well as in Category Common ..so in result i will select A category record instead of Common category row.

Comment: @r08 . . . Both of these queries do that.

Comment: In first one ...Incorrect syntax near 'seqnum'.

Comment: @r08 . . . I fixed the typo.

Comment: now i am getting another one..Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to get one row for Common and one row for A. Here's a way:

```
SELECT  TOP(1) *
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   Category = 'Common' 

UNION ALL

SELECT  TOP(1) *
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   Category = 'A'
```

Comment: No..In table any no of record will be there...just i provided sample..but in result always prefered particular Category between common.

Comment: so in my case Name 'Test1' exists in Category A as well as in Category Common ..so in result i will select A one record not Common category row.

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understood. Can add this example to your question? (preferred with sample data and expected result)

Comment: i have updated question with current and expected result.

Comment: I added a new solution based on your updates. I hope I got it right this time